# Next.js getServerSideProps catches an icon request

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, getserversideprops

why is the getServerSideProps method catching the icon request
This is breaking my application
i can't figure out how to fix this

For example, I expect the address to be equal

```
/[dymaniclocale]/user
```

but in fact it is equal to

```
/[dymaniclocale]/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further is your route setup like: `/[dymaniclocale]/user.js` or `/[dymaniclocale]/[user].js`